# Thunderbird excessive disk

Tags: ubuntu, thunderbird

Thunderbird 16.01 on ubuntu 12.04.

I ran out of disk space on a new install of ubuntu 12.04 and I thought that was a bit strange - went hunting and thunderbird was eating up 96GB of disk space and was hungry for more. After a bit of reading I found the hint to "compact folders" and that reduced it back down to a manageable 2G.

However I then started having the same problem on another machine. On this machine it is on a 5G truecrypt partition (instead of encrypted home directory). Because it was only 5G it was much harder to do anything, I couldn't "compact folders" because it just got stuck with no disk space. I messed around trying to delete and archive stuff which has probably just made things worse.

This is immaped.

I'm back on the machine with ~90G available disk space to play with and I opened thunderbird and it is doing it again - it is now up to ~40G used and doesn't want to stop.

This doesn't seem to match up with other question I find which say "thunderbird is taking up a huuge 4G of space". Meet my 96G which only stopped because it ran out of space.

Any idea what is going on or how to stop it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem and it is related to this bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=803843

As stated in the "description" of the bug, "repairing the folders" solves the problem.

I just watched the folders for which the messages continuously being downloaded, then repair them by following "Repair Folders in Mozilla Thunderbird" part of http://email.about.com/od/mozillathunderbirdtips/qt/How-To-Repair-Folders-In-Mozilla-Thunderbird.htm